# How to update LuaLatex on Debian to use 1.10.0 and 2019.20200218-1

Tags: luatex

I have two WSL2 distros running and whilst testing my LaTeX file via the command line, it seems to generate the PDF whilst using Ubuntu.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\overfullrule=0pt
\newcommand{\cvspace}{\vskip 1.2em}

\directlua{
  \directlua {
  luaotfload.add_multiscript("cjk",
      {
        Hang = "Noto Serif CJK KR:mode=harf;script=hang;",
        Hani = "Noto Serif CJK TC:mode=harf;script=hani;",
        Kana = "Noto Serif CJK JP:mode=harf;script=kana;",
        Hira = "Noto Serif CJK JP:mode=harf;script=hira;",
      }
    )
  }
}

\setmainfont[RawFeature={multiscript=cjk}]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
Japanese: 読サ統転ン務6危キリイ日記属して帯記ネヌイナ分碁モチワエ返地ゅびはン広沼とおは通国ふま指区ロウイ観提ニユ族曲トク車也むンり拡極保なにづか揚状侍勃ねラび。操みん強智そた締窟ねぴ悪6上手ルぜづて種当止タセ説当ね読寮クや減8様ケリトク認川るす差禁音策きがぜえ足94練ぴむびょ。
Chinese: 关于数学部分
Korean: 헌법재판소에서 법률의 위헌결정,
Others: 用@ \$ 和 测试中文
\end{document}
```

however, if I use the same .tex file on Debian I get the following error:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/LKey.tex))[\directlua]:1: at
tempt to call field 'add_multiscript' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.17   }
```

I have a feeling its because of the version of texlive. On my Ubuntu distro my version is as follows:

```
$ lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)

Execute  'luatex --credits'  for credits and version details.

There is NO warranty. Redistribution of this software is covered by
the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2 or (at your option)
any later version. For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the LuaTeX source.

LuaTeX is Copyright 2019 Taco Hoekwater and the LuaTeX Team.
```

Packages installed on Ubuntu:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep "tex"
    
    WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
    
    fonts-texgyre/focal,now 20180621-3 all [installed,automatic]
    gettext-base/focal,now 0.19.8.1-10build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
    html2text/focal,now 1.3.2a-25 amd64 [installed]
    latex2html/focal,now 2019.2-debian1-1 all [installed]
    liblocale-gettext-perl/focal,now 1.07-4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
    libptexenc1/focal,now 2019.20190605.51237-3build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
    libsynctex2/focal,now 2019.20190605.51237-3build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
    libtexlua53/focal,now 2019.20190605.51237-3build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
    libtexluajit2/focal,now 2019.20190605.51237-3build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
    libtext-charwidth-perl/focal,now 0.04-10 amd64 [installed,automatic]
    libtext-iconv-perl/focal,now 1.7-7 amd64 [installed,automatic]
    libtext-wrapi18n-perl/focal,now 0.06-9 all [installed,automatic]
    plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text/focal-updates,now 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
    preview-latex-style/focal,now 11.91-2ubuntu2 all [installed,automatic]
    tex-common/focal,now 6.13 all [installed,automatic]
    tex-gyre/focal,now 20180621-3 all [installed,automatic]
    texlive-base/focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed,automatic]
    texlive-binaries/focal,now 2019.20190605.51237-3build2 amd64 [installed]
    texlive-fonts-extra-links/focal,now 2019.202000218-1 all [installed,automatic]
    texlive-fonts-extra/focal,now 2019.202000218-1 all [installed]
    texlive-fonts-recommended/focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed]
    texlive-latex-base/focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed]
    texlive-latex-extra/focal,now 2019.202000218-1 all [installed,automatic]
    texlive-latex-recommended/focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed,automatic]
    texlive-luatex/focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed]
    texlive-pictures/focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed,automatic]
    texlive-plain-generic/focal,now 2019.202000218-1 all [installed,automatic]
    texlive/focal,now 2019.20200218-1 all [installed]
```

On my Debian distro:

```
$ lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)

Execute  'luatex --credits'  for credits and version details.

There is NO warranty. Redistribution of this software is covered by
the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2 or (at your option)
any later version. For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the LuaTeX source.

LuaTeX is Copyright 2018 Taco Hoekwater and the LuaTeX Team.
```

Packages installed on Debian:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep "tex"

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

chktex/stable,now 1.7.6-2+b1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
context-modules/stable,now 20181123-1 all [installed,automatic]
context/stable,now 2018.04.04.20181118-1 all [installed,automatic]
fonts-texgyre/stable,now 20180621-3 all [installed,automatic]
latex-cjk-all/stable,now 4.8.4+git20170127-2 all [installed,automatic]
latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp/stable,now 1.23 all [installed,automatic]
latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp/stable,now 1.23 all [installed,automatic]
latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp/stable,now 1.23 all [installed,automatic]
latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp/stable,now 1.23 all [installed,automatic]
latex-cjk-chinese/stable,now 4.8.4+git20170127-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
latex-cjk-common/stable,now 4.8.4+git20170127-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab/stable,now 0.20050817-17 all [installed,automatic]
latex-cjk-japanese/stable,now 4.8.4+git20170127-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
latex-cjk-korean/stable,now 4.8.4+git20170127-2 all [installed,automatic]
latex-cjk-thai/stable,now 4.8.4+git20170127-2 all [installed,automatic]
latexdiff/stable,now 1.3.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
latexmk/stable,now 1:4.61-0.1 all [installed,automatic]
libdjvulibre-text/stable,now 3.5.27.1-10 all [installed,automatic]
liblocale-gettext-perl/stable,now 1.07-3+b4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libptexenc1/stable,now 2018.20181218.49446-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libsynctex2/stable,now 2018.20181218.49446-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libtexlua52/stable,now 2018.20181218.49446-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libtexlua53/stable,now 2018.20181218.49446-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libtexluajit2/stable,now 2018.20181218.49446-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libtext-bibtex-perl/stable,now 0.85-2+b1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libtext-charwidth-perl/stable,now 0.04-7.1+b1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libtext-csv-perl/stable,now 1.99-1 all [installed,automatic]
libtext-csv-xs-perl/stable,now 1.38-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libtext-glob-perl/stable,now 0.10-1 all [installed,automatic]
libtext-iconv-perl/stable,now 1.7-5+b7 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libtext-roman-perl/stable,now 3.5-2 all [installed,automatic]
libtext-unidecode-perl/stable,now 1.30-1 all [installed,automatic]
libtext-wrapi18n-perl/stable,now 0.06-7.1 all [installed,automatic]
preview-latex-style/stable,now 11.91-2 all [installed,automatic]
tex-common/stable,now 6.11 all [installed,automatic]
tex-gyre/stable,now 20180621-3 all [installed,automatic]
texinfo/stable,now 6.5.0.dfsg.1-4+b1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
texlive-base/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-bibtex-extra/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-binaries/stable,now 2018.20181218.49446-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
texlive-extra-utils/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-font-utils/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-fonts-extra-doc/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-fonts-extra-links/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-fonts-extra/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed]
texlive-fonts-recommended-doc/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-fonts-recommended/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed]
texlive-formats-extra/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-full/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed]
texlive-games/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-generic-recommended/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-humanities-doc/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-humanities/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-arabic/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-chinese/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-cjk/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-cyrillic/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-czechslovak/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-english/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-european/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-french/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-german/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-greek/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-italian/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-japanese/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-korean/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-other/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-polish/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-portuguese/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-lang-spanish/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-latex-base-doc/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-latex-base/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-latex-extra-doc/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-latex-extra/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed]
texlive-latex-recommended-doc/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-latex-recommended/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-luatex/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed]
texlive-metapost-doc/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-metapost/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-music/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-pictures-doc/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-pictures/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-plain-generic/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-pstricks-doc/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-pstricks/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-publishers-doc/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-publishers/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-science-doc/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-science/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive-xetex/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed,automatic]
texlive/stable,now 2018.20190227-2 all [installed]
```

I can see on Ubuntu the version for LuaLatex is 1.10.0 using packages on 2019.202000218 version, which is the texlive version I believe. However, in Debian Lualatex version is 1.07.0 and the packages are using 2018.20190227-2.

How can I get Debian to generate the PDF as it does on Ubuntu on Debian? As mentioned above I suspect I need to update the versions, but how do I go about getting Lualatex on version 1.10.0 and having the packages on 2019.202000218 on Debian? Essentially, how can I get Debian to match what I have on my Ubuntu?

Comment: both versions are rather old, you could update both systems with an install of texlive 2021 from tug.org you have luatex 1.10 and 1.07, the current texlive release is `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021)`

Comment: I was able to update it to 2021, but doesn't look like my tex file generates the expected PDF. Either I need to get 2020 version or match what I have on Ubuntu, although I am not sure what I did for Ubuntu. How do I get 2020 texlive or match what I have on Ubuntu?